# Keep replacing duplicate rows until there are none left?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got one data frame (df1) to sample rows from, for example:

```
name age
name1 7
name2 31
name3 31
name4 34
name5 100
name6 1
name7 35
name8 27
name9 23
name10 3
name11 21
name12 2
name13 50
name14 86
```

And another data frame (df2) which I fill with random rows from the first data frame, for example:

```
name age
name4 34
name2 31
name11 21
name12 2
name6 1
name14 86
```

In my code I to choose a few rows (5 in the example) from df2 to overwrite with (5) random rows from df1.

```
random_df2 <- sample(1:nrow(df2),5,replace=FALSE)
df2[random_df2] <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1),5,replace=FALSE)]
```

But the problem is I don't want duplicates in df2.

If there are duplicate rows in df2, the code should keep sampling rows from df1 until all rows in df2 are unique.

I'm thinking something like (pseudocode):

```
while(there are duplicate rows in df2) {
rowNums <- get the row numbers of rows that are not unique
num <- get the number of rows not unique
      df2[rowNums,]<- sample(df1[sample(1:nrow(df1),num,replace=FALSE)]
}
```

Not sure if it's the best way to achieve the result in r..

Comment: Wait, you're replacing rows in df1 from df2 after replacing rows in df2 from df1? How would you expect it to stay unique if you're replacing df1 with rows originally taken from df1? The only way for it to stay unique is if it just switches 2 already existing rows (or keeps them identical). And if that's what you're trying to do, there are much, much easier ways then this. I think this question needs more detail about what it's trying to do, it sounds like this is just one step in a process

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm not trying to replace rows in df1 from df2. Just wrote the wrong thing in the comment. Your answer looks close to what I'm looking for, will run it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just take a sample from those that are not already in `df2`?

Maybe something like this:

```
# Set up example data
df1 <- data.frame(name=paste0('name', 1:20), age=sample(1:100, 20, T))
df2 <- df1[sample(1:nrow(df1), 10), ]

# Get names in df1 that are not in df2
df1_candidates <- setdiff(df1$name, df2$name)

# Sample from the df1 set not in df2 already
df2_replacements <- df1[df1$name %in% sample(df1_candidates, 5), ]

# Replace 5 random rows in df2 with the sampled replacements
random_df2 <- sample(1:nrow(df2), 5)
df2[random_df2, ] <- df2_replacements
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first find out what rows are included in df1 that aren't included in df2. dplyr's `anti_join` is perfect for this, as is its `sample_n` function.

```
library(dplyr)

rows_replace <- 1:5
num_replace <- length(rows_replace)

new_rows <- df1 %>%
    anti_join(df2[-rows_replace, ]) %>%
    sample_n(num_replace)

df2[rows_replace, ] <- new_rows
```